# What is the meaning of 「一人」in the following sentence?

Tags: usage, word-usage

> 今、女性**一人**が生む子どもの数が減ってきている。つまり、少子化が進んできている。 Now, the amount of women that give birth to a child is decreasing. That is to say, the declining birth rates are advancing.

What is the role of 「一人」? To me, the sentence still makes sense without it.

What is the difference between the following sentences?

> 今、女性**一人**が生む子どもの数…
>
> 今、女性が生む子どもの数…

Comment: Not much, as I can't find any object in my sentences no matter how many times I read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpret it like this:

> 女性が生む子どもの数

The number of children that women give birth to.

> 女性**一人**が生む子どもの数

The number of children that **one** woman gives birth to. In other words, the number of children born per woman.

Comment: what about「一人の女性が生む子どもの数」?

Comment: Opened a question for this doubt [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70693/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%a5%b3%e6%80%a7%e4%b8%80%e4%ba%ba-and-%e4%b8%80%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e5%a5%b3%e6%80%a7)